# Can I do voltage division for parallel resistors only?

Tags: voltage, resistors, voltage-divider, parallel

I understand that voltage division is possible for resistors that go "one after another". However, I was asked to do this for resistors that are parallel. But I could not find any info on that matter, plus some sources say that it is impossible. (I also kinda think it is not) So, could you please help me out here. Is it possible to do with just parallel resistors or I should mix both ways of connecting? And why?

Comment: Are you sure you were asked to build a _voltage_ divider with parallel resistors? As the answers already say, there is not much to see. But what you do get, is a _current_ divider.

Comment: Yeah, it says voltage divider. I guess the question is incorrect after all. Thanks for helping

Comment: what is the request wording exactly? ... please add the info to your question, not in a comment

Answer (score 2):

For resistors (or anything) in parallel, the voltage across them will be exactly the same ideally.

However the current through each will, in general, be different.

Comment: That makes for very boring voltage division equations.

Comment: If for example I have to parallel resistors  R1 and R2 1000 Om each the total resistance R is 500 Om. So R kinda counts for 1 resistor. But in order to have a divider I need two resistors at least. That means I need another non - parallel resistor...

Comment: @Nadia Correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible.

And easiest corner case.

Parallel resistors share the same equal voltage over both of them without dividing.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage division only works for series branches.

$$V_x = \frac {R_x} {R_T} \ V_T $$

where:

- \$V_x\$ is the voltage drop of the target *series* resistance.
- \$R_x\$ is the target *series* resistance.
- \$R_T\$ is the *total series resistance*.
- \$V_T\$ is the voltage applied to the *series* branch.

For parallel branches: Find the equivalent resistance for the parallel branches (making them series) and then do voltage division.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot! That makes sense